# effective and unconditional upper bound for the smallest quadratic residue

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-residues

Let $p$ be a prime number, and let $r=r(p)$ be the smallest prime number with $(r/p)=1$. The classical result of Linnik-Vinogradov (based on Burgess) implies that $r\ll_\epsilon p^{1/4+\epsilon}$, but it is non-effective. The more recent work of Lamzouri, Li, and Soundararajan [Math. Comp. 84 (2015),
2391--2412] implies the effective bound $r\ll(\log p)^2$ assuming GRH. (I thank the user *Lucia* for drawing my attention to this work when answering my previous question.)

I wonder what is the best known upper bound which is both **effective** and **unconditional**.

I know that using a Tatuzawa-type result one can get smth "effective with one exception". This is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Remark: In the **special case** that $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, the Heegner--Baker--Stark theorem implies that $r \le \sqrt{p/3}$ for $p>163$. (No small split primes would imply $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-p})$ had class number $1$.)

Comment: When $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, one can get a $O(\sqrt{p})$ bound more simply: Choose the largest nonnegative even $u$ with $u < \sqrt{p-1}$. Then $1 < p-u^2 = O(\sqrt{p})$ and $p-u^2$ is odd. Let $r$ be an odd prime dividing $p-u^2$. Then $p\equiv u^2\pmod{r}$, so $p$ is a square mod $r$. By QR, $r$ is a square mod $p$.

Comment: There are effective versions of Burgess' bound. Do they not make the Linnik-Vinogradov bound effective?

Comment: GH: Burgess is, of course, effective, but non-effectiveness of LV is caused by Siegel's zero.

Comment: The Lamzouri-Li-Soundararajan bound based on GRH (their Corollary 1.1) would be better expressed as $r(p) < (\log p)^2$ for prime $p > 3$ rather than $r(p) \ll (\log p)^2$, since Bach had shown the GRH-bound $r(p) \leq 2(\log p)^2$ about 30 years ago.

Comment: KConrad: I believe that Bach assumed ERH, not GRH

Comment: (In case it helps, here is a quick (perhaps canonical?) reference that makes the use of Siegel's ineffective lower bound clear: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa13/aa1317.pdf , note displays (1) and (2).)

Comment: When I wrote "GRH" above, I meant "GRH for Dirichlet $L$-functions" (same as  "ERH" in Bach's paper).  And in the paper by LLS, they use the term "GRH" with the same meaning, not anything broader. From the start of their Section 1.1: "Bach showed, on GRH, that the least prime $p$ that does not lie in $H$ is less than $2(\log q)^2$".  The only $L$-functions occurring in the LLS paper are Dirichlet $L$-functions.

Comment: Keith: "does not lie" is not what I am looking for; I want "does lie" :)

Comment: The result from LLS that I quote is their Theorem 1.4.

And, ERH in Bach's article is not GRH; it is RH for all Hecke L-functions; see the bottom of page 360 of his article.

Comment: I agree Bach's paper begins with Hecke $L$-functions, but for the purpose of bounding the smallest nonzero integer mod m lying outside a proper subgroup of the units mod m, all he needs is GRH for Dirichlet $L$-functions. See section 6 of the paper (esp. Theorems 2 and 3 on p.  372) where $\chi$ is a nontrivial Dirichlet character mod $m$.  When Bach's thesis came out earlier in book form ("Analytic Methods in the Analysis and Design of Number-Theoretic Algorithms", MIT Press, 1985, esp. Theorem C on p. 19), the only $L$-functions he uses there are those attached to Dirichlet characters.

Comment: I read your question too quickly, and thought you wanted a bound for the least non-residue mod $p$. My apologies.

Comment: To further confirm KConrad remark: Bach, on page 7, line -5, of the book mentioned wrote "The Riemann Hypothesis asserts that $Re \rho =1/2$ for every such root of $\zeta$, and the Extended Riemann Hypothesis asserts the same for every such root of a Dirichlet L-function". So in the cited book he used ERH as a synonym for GRH.